# How to prove function $f(x,y)=y^xe^{-y}$ is both logarithmically concave and logarithmically convex

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

[image]How to prove function $f(x,y)=y^xe^{-y}$ in $x \in R_+^n$ for all $ y \gt 0$ is both logarithmically concave and logarithmically convex(i.e. $\log f(x,y)=x \log y-y$  is both a concave function and a convex function)?

My problem comes from  [solutions manual to Convex Optimizaton](http://egrcc.github.io/docs/math/cvxbook-solutions.pdf), exercise 3.52 at page 69

Comment: @Finley : Why do you enclose \ge and \gt within curly braces? That is what prevented them from having proper spacing, so that you see $A{\ge}B$ instead of $A\ge B. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy : Thanks for your tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says “log-convex (as well as log-concave) in $x$”, which means that if we keep $y$ constant, then $\log f(x,y)$ is an affine function of $x$, which is in fact the case.